# Is is still considered a BFS algorithm if I modify it A little bit?

Tags: python, algorithm, search, artificial-intelligence, breadth-first-search

So I'm trying to create a program that finds the shortest path from nodeA to nodeB, however, I want to block certain nodes so that it would find another path. I'm not really aiming for an optimal code here I'm just trying things out, exploring etc.

Is it still considered a BFS if I modify it a little?

Comment: It might sound obvious, but if this is still a breadth-first search then it is still a "BFS algorithm".

Comment: If you "block certain nodes", then you are actually reducing the graph (removing nodes and/or edges), which means you are performing BFS on a reduced graph. What changes then is not the algorithm but the graph.

Comment: You can call that a partial-BFS or constrained-BFS.

Comment: You are running BFS on an implicit graph, which is actually the usual case.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_graph

Comment: On a theoretical point of view, I agree with all that is said. On a practical point of view, I tend to think that you can call your algorithm the way you want, if you add "modified" in front of the name, nobody will ever tell you anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it still is a BFS, with just a few constraints. The essence of BFS algorithm is the way it explores the graph, you are just exploring a subgraph (through filtering out a bit of it).